# Bounding a difference of sums

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, summation

I have two sums $$S_{10} = 40\left(\frac{1}{(20+1)^2} + \frac{1}{(20+3)^2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{(20+19)^2}\right) \\ S_{20} = 80\left(\frac{1}{(40+1)^2} + \frac{1}{(40+3)^2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{(40+39)^2}\right)$$

and I'm trying to find an upper bound on $$\left| S_{10}-S_{20}\right|$$

with 2 decimal places of accuracy.

There are twice as many terms in $S_{20}$ so I'm thinking I can group this like $$\left| S_{10}-S_{20}\right| = \left| 40\left(\frac{1}{(20+1)^2} - 2\left(\frac{1}{(40+1)^2} + \frac{1}{(40+3)^2}\right) \right) + 40\left(\cdots\right.\right|$$

Then I can just focus on the terms like $$\frac{1}{(20+1)^2} - 2\left(\frac{1}{(40+1)^2} + \frac{1}{(40+3)^2}\right)$$

I'm given the hint that $\frac 1{n^2}-\frac 1{m^2} \le 2(m-n)$ for $m \gt n \gt 1$.

So trying to use this I get $$\frac{1}{(20+1)^2} - 2\left(\frac{1}{(40+1)^2} + \frac{1}{(40+3)^2}\right) \le 2\left(\frac{41\times 43}{\sqrt{2(41^2+43^2)}}-21\right)$$

This looks like a pretty complex term and if I carry on with this approach I going to get something really long and ugly.  I just wanted to ask if this is the right approach here.  Should I just carry on and find the bound each one of the other terms and then the total bound should be less that the sum of the upper bounds of each term?  Or am I missing the "easy" way to do this?

---

I'm only supposed to solve this for these two particular sums, but if it's easier to figure out the general formula, both of these two sums come from different $n$ values of the sum:

$$S_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{4n}{(2n+(2k+1))^2}$$